# Pointer decay warning (C26485) and passing NOTIFYICONDATA member variable to _tcscpy_s

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis

Sample code:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CreateBackupTrayNotification(CString strInfoTitle, CString strInfo, CString strTip)
{
    ::ZeroMemory(&m_sNTD, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));

    m_sNTD.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    m_sNTD.hWnd = GetSafeHwnd();
    m_sNTD.uID = 0;
    m_sNTD.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_INFO;

    m_sNTD.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;

    m_sNTD.uCallbackMessage = WM_MSA_BACKUP_NOTIFICATION;
    m_sNTD.uTimeout = 20000; // 20 Seconds
    m_sNTD.hIcon = LoadIcon(AfxGetResourceHandle(),
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME));

    _tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szInfoTitle, gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfoTitle.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfoTitle);
    _tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szInfo, gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfo.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfo);
    _tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szTip, gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strTip.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strTip);

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &m_sNTD);
}
```

Ignore the `(LPCTSTR)` casts because I have added a global `pragma` to ignore the warnings. My question here relates to these lines:

```
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szInfoTitle, gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfoTitle.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfoTitle);
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szInfo, gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfo.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfo);
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szTip, gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strTip.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strTip);
```

`m_sNTD` is a [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa) structure:

```
typedef struct _NOTIFYICONDATAA {
  DWORD cbSize;
  HWND  hWnd;
  UINT  uID;
  UINT  uFlags;
  UINT  uCallbackMessage;
  HICON hIcon;
#if ...
  CHAR  szTip[64];
#else
  CHAR  szTip[128];
#endif
  DWORD dwState;
  DWORD dwStateMask;
  CHAR  szInfo[256];
  union {
    UINT uTimeout;
    UINT uVersion;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
  CHAR  szInfoTitle[64];
  DWORD dwInfoFlags;
  GUID  guidItem;
  HICON hBalloonIcon;
} NOTIFYICONDATAA, *PNOTIFYICONDATAA;
```

I get the dreaded pointer decay warning ([C26485](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26485?view=msvc-160)). As you can see, the member variables in question are:

- `CHAR  szInfoTitle[64];`
- `CHAR  szInfo[256];`
- `CHAR  szTip[128];`

Side note: Not sure what that `if ...` is on about. Also, my structure is actually pointing to a `NOTIFYICONDATAW` so the member variables are `WCHAR`.

Anyway, I have understand that I can suppress a pointer decay warning by using `&varname[0]`. But in this case it is not working:

```
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.&szInfoTitle[0], gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfoTitle.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfoTitle);
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.&szInfo[0], gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfo.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfo);
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.&szTip[0], gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strTip.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strTip);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place for `&` would be:

```cpp
_tcscpy_s(&m_sNTD.szInfoTitle[0], gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfoTitle.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfoTitle); 
_tcscpy_s(&m_sNTD.szInfo[0], gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strInfo.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strInfo); 
_tcscpy_s(&m_sNTD.szTip[0], gsl::narrow<rsize_t>(strTip.GetLength()) + 1, (LPCTSTR)strTip);
```

But actually you are using `_tcscpy_s` wrong. The second parameter is destination buffer size, not source. `_s` functions are meant to be **s**ecure by checking buffer size; by lying about it, you defeat the purpose of this security.

Just omit the second parameter and let it be deduced, this should also fix the warning (really fix, not suppress):

```cpp
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szInfoTitle, (LPCTSTR)strInfoTitle); 
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szInfo, (LPCTSTR)strInfo); 
_tcscpy_s(m_sNTD.szTip, (LPCTSTR)strTip);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and corrections! Been wrong all these years!